# How to group results in SQL from related tables?

Tags: php, sql, sql-optimization

This is related to an [earlier question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002166/how-to-use-sql-to-avoid-queries-within-loops) but unfortunately I don't think I worded my problem clearly enough as I did not get a complete answer to my question.

I have two tables, one called Groups and one called Items. What I would like to do is select all groups, and then within each group select all items so I end up with something like this:

**Heading 1** <- Group

- One <- Item
- Two <- Item

**Heading 2** <- Group

- One <- Item
- Two <- Item

In my original post you can see the code I used to originally achieve this, which was essentially a loop within a loop first selecting all groups then all items within the group. I know having a SQL query loop within a SQL query loop is a bad idea, so thanks to some helpful SO members I now have this code:

```
$query = "SELECT g.ID AS GRPID, g.Description AS GrpDesc,i.ID AS ITEM_ID, i.Description AS ItemDescription
              FROM Groups_Inv g
          LEFT JOIN Items_Inv i
          ON g.ID=i.grpID
          ORDER BY g.SortNum ASC";
     try { 
                $result = odbc_exec($connect,$query); 
                if($result){ 
                   while ($groups = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo    "<li title='".$groups['GrpDesc']."' class='category'>
                <h3><span><a class='category'>".$groups['GrpDesc']."</a></span></h3>
                <ul class='sub-menu'>\n";

            echo "<li class='select'>
                <input type='radio' class='addRow'>
                    <label for='".$groups['ITEM_ID']."'>
                    ".$groups['ItemDescription']."
                    </label>
                  </li>\n";

            echo    "</ul>
                </li>\n";
        }
                } 
                else { 
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to connect."); 
                } 
    }
```

This selects all groups that have corresponding items, but it does not group all items under their group header, so I end up with results like this:

**Heading 1**

- One

**Heading 1**

- Two

How can I modify this so that all groups are listed only once and all items for each group are correctly listed under the group heading?

Comment: SQL query seems perfect. try it by using SELECT * FROM ...
and fetch particular values from array('field_name').

Comment: @RonakPatel The query itself is fine, what I want to know is how do I group all results so each group heading is only shown once and all related items are listed below it?

Comment: ok.. for that you need to use for loop. $groups[$i]['ItemDescription']. you need to use another query to count every possible elements and bind that value with for loop limit.

Comment: @RonakPatel Having a SQL query within a loop is what I was trying to avoid with this code. My original code I linked to used a SQL query within a loop, but on very large lists this can very quickly consume a lot of server resources

Comment: No. I am not telling you that put your sql query in the loop. but you need to get all the items under same group. so, you need to put all your items through for loop.

Comment: @RonakPatel I see what you mean but I'm not following the specific logic. What would go in the for loop? for ($i = 0; $i ???; $i++)

Comment: ??? = number of elements you will get. and that you can find through SQL query.

Comment: @RonakPatel Sorry Ronak, I very much appreciate your support but I'm feeling pretty silly right now as I'm not seeing how to tie this together in my code. Could you provide a short sample of what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if you are getting problem in this code. I used separate class for query.

```
class tank extends mysqli{
public function curr_group_content($a)
{
    $query ="SELECT g.ID AS GRPID, g.Description AS GrpDesc,i.ID AS ITEM_ID, i.Description AS ItemDescription
                    FROM Groups_Inv g
                    LEFT JOIN Items_Inv i
                    ON g.ID=i.grpID
                    ORDER BY g.SortNum ASC";  

        if ($stmt = parent::prepare($query)){
            $stmt->execute(); 
            $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

            while ( $field = $meta->fetch_field() ) {
                $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
            }

           call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

              while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
                  $x = array();
                  foreach( $row as $key => $val ) {
                     $x[$key] = $val;
                  }
                  $results[] = $x;
               }       

           return $results;
           $stmt->close();
        }//END PREPARE
        else{trigger_error($this->error, E_USER_NOTICE);}
}
}

$clients = new tank();
$data = array();
$events = $clients->curr_group_content();
$eventscount = sizeof($events);
  for($i=0;$i<$eventscount;$i++){
    $data['item'][] = $events[$i]['item'];
  }
```